# How to display all elements of a vector within lldb?

Tags: c++, lldb

How can I print all elements of a vector in lldb?

If you execute (`v` is a vector):

```
expr v
```

It displays a max number of elements thats set to 256 by default. But I want to print an unabridged version/whole vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the maximum number of displayed elements using:

```
settings set target.max-children-count 100000
```

(Setting it to 100000 elements)